# Parsing file name from String

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a simple regex that starts with `url` and ends with `jpg)` to extract the string `url(file:///C:\\Testing\\external\\thex-2_rtfimage_1.jpg)`.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class ExtractFile
{
     public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = 
     "this is url(file:///C:\\Testing\\external\\thex-2_rtfimage_1.jpg) which is attached";

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("url");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
        // check all occurance
        while (matcher.find()) {
           System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
           System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
           System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Your are welcome! Continue your research

Comment: the most simple regex that starts with url and ends with jpg is `urljpg`. :) You need to specify your question more clearly.

Comment: Try with something like this: `url\([^\)]+\.jpg\)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following pattern should work to detect anything that starts with a `url` and finishes with `jpg`

```
((url)[\w\W\d\D]+(.jpg)+(\W){1}) // matches `url(` to start, anything in the middle that you will use for url names, followed by `.jpg`, and a bracket `)`
```

```js
var text = "url(file:///C:\\Testing\\external\\thex-2_rtfimage_1.jpg)";
var x = text.match(/((url)[\w\W\d\D]+(.jpg)+(\W){1})/g);
alert(x);
```

The demonstration uses JavaScript as I went to JSFiddle to work the solution out. But the pattern is usable in Java too.

Another solution for your pattern can be:

```
\burl([\w\W])+(.jpg\))
```

This matches using a word boundary (\b)where it starts with `url`followed by a match for one or more word, non-word,digit, or non-digit characters, and then .jpg ending with a right parentheses `)`. It would've been better if you provided your a sample of your expected input and answer. But given your statement, this is what I came up with. But there could very well be other working solutions!

Comment: The flavor here is Java, which has the DOTALL modifier, but even in JavaScript `[\w\W\d\D]+` is ridiculously excessive.  `[\w\W]+` or `[\d\D]+` would be fine, but in this case `.+` is all you need, because there's no chance the substrings you're matching will contain newlines. However, it should be `.+?` or `[^()]+`, because your regex will find everything from the first `url` to the last `.jpg` in one match.  Also, you don't need any of those parentheses, the `.` should be escaped, the `(\W)` is pointless, and `{1}` has no effect at all.  This is a bad answer.

Comment: @AlanMoore      It has nothing to do with Java actually. ECMAscript format for regex, Java regex, and Python regex are all pretty much identical, Simply demonstrating a pattern with JavaScript doesn't make this invalid. I leave it to the OP to decide if this is a bad answer.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing you for using the wrong flavor, I was criticizing the regex itself.  The new one is much better, but you still don't need those parens. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use word boundaries and `.*?` to match text between `url` and `jpg`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\burl.*?jpg\\b");
```